# VLC displaying only a small portion of the output then crashes when reading SDP file

Tags: video-streaming, wireshark, h.264, vlc, transport-stream

I'm trying to play RTP stream using VLC but its only showing a black with a little bit of the video output then crashes after.(see image).

[image: scap]

This is the content of the SDP file:

```
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 103
c=IN IP4 239.194.115.71
a=rtpmap:103 H264/90000
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: enable the vlc/ffmpeg logs and share them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the link directly without the SDP file by using using the MPEG-TS demuxer feature of VLC.

[image: sample]
or
[image: 2sample]